# jQuery website pre loader, like Tuts+ (example website)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

I was trying to find a jQuery plugin that will achieve similar preloading effect like on this website [Example](http://hub.tutsplus.com), After intense research I wasn't able to find anything useful. Can anyone suggest a plugin that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your [Example](http://hub.tutsplus.com/) page and inspect it with firebug ... If you remove the `class="ready"` from the body tag then you will see the actuall div that is overlayed over the entire page.

So all it is, is a div with transparency and an image at the center with a very high z-index.

When everything is loaded underneath you trigger a hide of the div ... and the page is there.

You could fire the hiding after the dom is ready or after a timeout etc...

Comment: lol, didn't see that loading thing and thought he was looking for a page preview plugin :)